# How to change default title of a github pull request

Tags: github, pull-request

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the format of a pull request title to my preference. 
Currently, when I open a pull request from a forked branch, the pull request sets the name of the branch as default title.

For example, I have a branch called `FB-123` and when I click on the 'Create pull request' button to open a pull request, the title is already set as 
`Fb-123` .

But I would like to set a template to be `[Fb-123]`.

Is this not a feature supported on github?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: hello, have you found how to do this?

Comment: Hi @Bruice .. unfortunately, i wasn't able to find a solution for this.. don't think it's possible..

Comment: As of 12-17-2021, I have searched high and low. This feature doesn't exist, but has been discussed in various issues on GH to no avail.

Comment: Hello, is there any updates? Maybe it is possible using some bot/actions/apps?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub do not have any feature to do this. Because that would make it difficult for others to reason about your change.